# Rails server file download crashing at send_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, sendfile, x-sendfile

I am working on downloading a file. My rails server crashes every time I download - when it reaches the `send_file` method.

Controller code:

```
file_path = '/home/rails/rails_app/public/test.csv'
send_file(file_path, options: {disposition: 'attachment', filename: File.basename(file_path)})
```

Server logs:

```
Sent file /home/rails/rails_app/public/test.csv  (0.1ms)
server #
```

This code was working on `rails 2.X` perfactly , but does not work while upgrading to `rails 4.2.7.1`

Comment: The logs show that your file was sent, not an error :( Maybe you are using `application\pdf` where it is supposed to be `application\csv`?

Comment: I have updated the code . Still same issue

Comment: You'll have to give us something to work on, that log you posted doesn't show an error, but a successful message.

Comment: If the file is in the application folder you could use relative path like `file_path = 'public/test.csv'`

Comment: Actually , after this server log , application server got down all the time. It crashes and exit completely. So I have that much of the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this and check?

```
File.open(file_path, 'r') do |f|
  send_data f.read
end
```

Comment: Awesome @jeet. You saved my lot of time